# Combining two PCs together

Tags: windows, combine

I wanna combine two old PCs together to be one PC and I wish that if anybody can tell me any solution because it would be hard for me to buy a new PC atm

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing that as parts from one PC may not be compatible with parts from another. Also, you cannot just "combine" two PCs into one, you need to choose which components you want from which PC and check if they are compatible with each other

Comment: I didn't imagine that thing like that may happen. Anyways lets wait if someone else has any idea, I hope.

Comment: Are they identical PCs?

Comment: Unfortunately they are not!

Comment: One runs with Gigabyte motherboard and Intel processor and the other runs with Abit motherboard and AMD processor

Comment: If they're identical or at least compatible each other, there you can go depending what hardware you set as "recipient". But if you're trying to combine different hardware (e.g. taking Intel processor for AMD-based motherboard), it doesn't work for all components & only compatible parts may used (HDD, RAM etc).

Comment: You cannot "combine" an Intel CPU with an AMD CPU.  Which components exactly do you want to use from each Pc.  Update your question in order to clarify your question

Comment: @Ramhound Well... All if possible

Comment: Can you please tell us the full specs of each computer?

Comment: @MohamedHatem your question currently is too broad to answer it's not possible to use an Intel motherboard with an ANd CPU and vice versa so EDIT your question and be specific of which components you want to use

Comment: @Ramhound My question clearly shows that I want use all components "I wanna combine two old PCs together to be one PC"

Comment: Which components exactly?  "All" is extremely broad and "all" is not possible

Comment: What about the VGA cards? I guess they are same. and what about the processor? One is Intel and the other on is AMD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The heart of most PCs can generally be considered the motherboard. It essentially determines the requirements for all other connected components. This is the item you want to pick first for any build.

Other PC components are not guaranteed to be compatible with each other but can roughly be divided into parts that are more or less likely to compatible.

*(Also note that laptop vs. desktop can bring it's own issues).*

Assuming both PCs are desktops:

**Least Compatible (Requires Research)**

- *CPU* - CPUs have very specific requirements and are almost certainly not interchangeable between random motherboards.
- *Memory* - Even though often much more compatible than CPUs, memory tends to be specific enough that simply swapping some into another computer is unlikely to yield satisfactory results (if it is even physically possible) .

**More Compatible (Still Not Guaranteed)**

- *Internal Cards (Graphics, Sound, Etc.)* - Non-integrated cards such as those used for graphics, sound, etc. tend to be interchangeable assuming you have the correct type of card slot available on the motherboard. Be aware you still often need additional drivers to make sure these cards work correctly once transplanted.
- *Hard Drive* - Internal and external hard drives tend to be interchangeable assuming (again) you have the correct connections available. External drives that use USB tend to be the most compatible.
- *Optical Drives* - Internal and external CD/DVD/Blu-ray drives are similar to hard drives and the same criteria apply.
- *Monitors* - Another hardware item that comes down to (mostly) connectors.

**Most Compatible**

- *External Keyboard and Mouse* - Even when there are connection differences (i.e. PS/2 vs. USB), it's often extremely simple to use these items on other computers. Wireless keyboards and mice can present more of a problem but usually are fine assuming you have access to dongles and drivers.

**???**

- *Power Supply* - Generic power supplies can often be swapped but not always. The likelihood of incompatibility goes up if the computer is from a specific manufacturer (e.g Dell) since they may use custom connections to the motherboard and these items (PSU and motherboard) may need to be a set.
- *Case* - Similar to power supply units, generic cases tend to be interchangeable. That said, again, custom manufacturers (e.g Dell) may use particularly standoff patterns or front panel connections that aren't necessarily compatible with other components.

In your case, I would pick one PC that was more "powerful" (had the best motherboard, processor and memory) and then cannabalize compatible parts from the second computer. I would skip swapping the PSU and case unless I had a good reason. I would pick items from the More/Most compatible categories above to target in my swap.

Comment: I'm confused about the categorising of memory as Least Compatible. I presume by memory you mean RAM, or at least that it includes RAM. Aren't there essentially only two factors to consider for RAM: the type (DDR2/3/4) and the speed (MHz)? Those two factors don't seem enough to me to warrant describing RAM as incompatible as the average motherboard. If you ensure those two boxes are ticked, which is very likely to be the case, I can't see no reason why RAM couldn't be easily swapped out from another PC.

Comment: If we're starting from the premise of building a PC, the high potential incompatibility of the mobo is only closely followed by the PSU. The PSU is the core component from which every other component in your system draws power, requiring you to choose a PSU whose wattage encompasses that of all other components. On top of that, most PSUs have a limited number of fixed connectors - meaning that you'll have to ensure the one you choose has enough (and the right ones) for all the devices you want to connect to it. Yes, unlike with the mobo, you can use splitters, but that can quickly get messy.

Comment: Regarding the PSU, I can agree in principle. It received the ??? treatment because after-market PSUs are often meant to work with a wide variety of motherboards (power/cabling issues aside).

Comment: Regarding RAM,  DDR/DDR2/DDR3/DDR4 is arguably a huge box to tick since each type uses physically different slots. Also, while OP says "two old PCs", if one is a workstation or tower server and the other isn't, you might also be dealing with an ECC vs. Non-ECC RAM situation (motherboards made for one type of memory may not work with the other type). Lastly, while I think it's rare, I have at least heard of Dual-Channel only motherboards (so pairing RAM would be essential in these cases).

Comment: But even for compatible sticks, MHz, CAS latency, timing and voltage can still be a concern if you want a system that is A) stable and B) isn't under-clocking faster sticks.